# How to swap arrays inside a 2 dimensional array in O(n) in Java

Tags: java, performance, swing

I am making a game of tetris. It is played in a R x C grid. now, to determine whether a block is filled up or not I am storing the boolean value of that block in a 2 dimensional array.
When all values in a row is true, or the row is filled, the row is deleted and replaced with rows above it, with the top most row being set to all zeroes.
Note that rows go 0 to R from top to bottom. (0 being top, R being bottom)
Now, this is by default an O(n^2) problem. But I want to do it in O(n). To do this, I intend to store only references of each rows in an array. Whenever a row is to be deleted, I only need to replace that row reference with previous row reference, the previous one with it's previous one's reference and so on. Then I only need to add a new empty row reference for the topmost row.
How can I do this

Comment: It looks like you already know *what* to do (replace current row with previous one few times). Which step you are having problem with? Hint: 2D array is simply **1D array containing references to other 1D arrays**. If we have 2D array like `int[][] matrix = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}}` then it is an 1D array of 1D `int[]` arrays. So at `matrix[0]` we have `ind[]` array `{1,2,3}` and at `matrix[1]` `{4,5,6}`. We can *replace specific rows* with other 1D arrays. We just need to assign other int[] array to `matrix[index]` like `matrix[0] = new int[]{9,8,7};` (now matrix will be `{9,8,7},{4,5,6}}`.

Comment: Does that mean I can simply do matrix[1] = matrix[0], and it will work in O(1)

Comment: Single `matrix[1] = matrix[0]` will be `O(1)`. Serie of `N` such "swaps" would be `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I thought array swapping works like c++ arrays in java

Comment: What `matrix[1]` holds as value in Java is *reference* to array object (each object has its own unique reference - you can think of it as unique number). So if `matrix[1]` holds ID like `42` and `matrix[0]` holds `52` then after `matrix[1] = matrix[0]` `matrix[1]` would also hold `52` (which is reference/identifier of some object - here array). It is same as `int x = 1; int y = 2;` and `x=y;` which would cause `x` to hold `2` (and that operation is also `O(1)`).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.